# How can I use Blenders Face Maps as a Selection input for Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to delete specific **faces** from my model in a Geometry Nodes node tree. What I am looking for is an easy way to manually specify which **faces** should get deleted. Deleting vertices is not an option, as the vertex area changes with the amount of subdivisions on the model (the selection then grows in an unwanted fashion, while face maps and material index data remains stable). Blender since a while offers the beautiful Face Maps in the mesh tab, which are perfectly suited for such a task.

What I'm missing is how to access that data from Geometry Nodes. Is there a way to do this? At the moment I'm working around the issue by abusing the Material Index data. Kind of does the same, but using Face Maps would be more flexible and a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Short and sweet: No, definitely not possible.

Face maps cannot be used in *Geometry Nodes*, unfortunately.

In *Geometry Nodes* you can only process data that is stored in a specific domain (*Points*, *Edges*, *Faces*, *Face Corners*, *Instances*). *Face Maps*, however, are not stored in any of these domains, but have their own data area, which contains *Faces*.

"Face Maps create custom gizmos to deform meshes by assigning faces to *Face Maps*." [Source](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/meshes/properties/object_data.html#bpy-types-facemaps)

So this is unfortunately the only valid answer to your question.